# Passing a List using $http.get request to webapi

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I passing a List using `$http.get` request to my webapi controller. The list seems to be `null`. Why?

angular:
[image]

webapi:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should use **POST** to send the `List<Billing>` to your WebApi. Change `System.Web.Http.HttpGet` to `System.Web.Http.HttpPost` in your WebApi.

In your dataService use something like this:

```
       function post(endpoint, data) {
            return $http.post(baseUrl + '/' + endpoint, data)
               .error(function (data, status) {
                   notify.error('Error sending data to ' + endpoint + ' (' + status + ')');
               });
        }
```